# Finding outliers in binary data

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, outliers, binary-data

Say you have data from 10 different sensors about the occurrence of some event - e.g. motion sensors. Each sensor records 1 if they detected the motion sensors and 0 if they didn't.

If you have 10 binary "reports" from these sensors, which should all ideally be identical, how can you detect outliers?

E.g. in case the reports are 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1 then the outliers are sensors 1, 5 and 10. 
E.g. in case the reports are 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0 then the outliers are sensors 5 and 8.

I looked at some literature on outlier detection in binary logistic regression but I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for as the data is purely binary. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Have you checked the distributions? Is there an outcome variable resulting from these 10 sensor readings?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please clarify your question a bit. Am I reading it correctly in the following way: you have 10 different sensors measuring the same phenomenon and these 10 sensors should all agree in an ideal world. Is that a correct description? – *Reviewer*

Comment: @Jon Which distributions? So each binary bit is bernoulli distirbuted and has some probability s of being 1, therefore a probability 1-s of being 0. They are independent (sorry, should have mentioned that). The outcome variable is that I'm trying to come up with some novel way to aggregate this date, and the method requires some knowledge of which sensors *may* be sending erroneous data.

Comment: @Jim Yes you are correct. They are all taking an independent binary measurement of the same measurand, and therefore a correct readings would be '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' if the measurand were 0 and '1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1' if it were 1.